# What does 'xxx' mean in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to looking for the meaning of 'xxxxxx' in Makefile as the below example.

```
## Variables and scripts
NCROOT            = `ncroot`
TEST_NAME         = apb_uart_rx_tx
```

what is the `ncroot`? Is this something variable?

How can I find where to declare ?

Comment: Please try to make your question clearer by adding context and purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backquotes are used to execute a program, and to use the output. The backquoted string (including backquotes) will be replaced with the program output. So, `${NCROOT}` will contain whatever the program `ncroot` writes to `stdout` *at this time*.

Just for the sake of completeness - please be aware that `ncroot` will be executed *each* time `${NCROOT}` is used. If one wants to cache and reuse the output, something like

```
NCROOT := $(shell ncroot)
```

might be preferrable.